# Python Data Structure to pop anywhere and push to the end in O(1)

Tags: python, data-structures

I was wondering,

is there any python data structure to pop from anywhere (using an object), remove from the front and push to the back in O(1)?

To prove its even possible lets look at the next data structure that can be implemented in C:
[image]
(Notice all the pointers are 2 way)
Thus we can:

pop(object) - lookup the object at the hashtable O(1) on average, remove it from the doubly linked list in O(1), and remove it from the hashtable in O(1).

popFront() - look at the front of the list in O(1), remove it from the hashtable in O(1), remove it from the doubly linked list in O(1).

PushBack() - add the item to the back of the doubly linked list O(1), add the item to the hashtable O(1) on average.

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean by indexing the dictionary into a linked list, can you elaborate?

Comment: you can more-or-less do this with a standard dict, it's nothing like a doubly linked list though.

Comment: @wim, the problem with a standard dict would be supporting the popFront and pushBack methods, Dict doesnt maintain order (maybe it does? im not really a python programmer).

Comment: wrong, dict does maintain (insertion) order, since Python 3.7, and it insert/remove in average O(1) amortized.  The part that is missing vs linked list is any concept of next or previous node, since the underlying data structure in the implementation can be full of "holes" (tombstone markers from deleted items)

Comment: @yellowcard123 `dict` absolutely maintains insertion order. To get the first and last elements, in the most up to date versions of python, you can use `first_key, first_value = next(iter(mydict.items()))` or `last_key, last_value = next(reversed(mydict.items()))`

Comment: ok, cool, so now my question sums up to this: if i have a dict (lets say the values dont matter) {"hi", "bye", "blue", "green"} and I delete "bye", will the order still be {"hi", "blue", "green"} or can it change with deletions?

Comment: Order will not change with deletion.

Comment: All operations in O(1) or just the push-to-back?

Comment: @yellowcard123 no, `dict` objects are *ordered data structures*. The *maintain insertion order*

Comment: PushBack() will be O(N) if you just naively use a dict. However, I believe if you "reverse" it, you can get PushBack in O(1)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why would pushback be O(N)?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Huh? PushBack would just be a normal dict setitem (possibly with an O(1) check if it's already in dict)

Comment: @wim @KellyBundy maybe I'm getting it mixed up in my head, by "back" we mean to the *beginning*, no? In which case, you'd have to shift all the items in the dict already, so somethig like `new = {obj: None, **old}`

Comment: pushfront would be add to beginning (e.g. appendleft for deque) pushback would be just append

Comment: @wim oh jeez, yes, sorry, I am all turned around. Like the *front and back of a line* is the orientation I have in my head

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comments.

Just use a regular dict.

Python dicts keep the order of insertion so:

```
pop(object) - del dict[Int]

popFront - dict.pop(next(iter(dict.items())))

PushBack - dict[Int] = Object
```

Comment: That popFront doesn't work and the fixed version isn't O(1).

Comment: You have almost the right idea, but the "objects" must not be the keys of the dict, they need to be the values of the dict. You can autogenerate integer keys.  I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @wim How do you do pop if they're the values?

Comment: I guess you'd have to pop by integer key, and maintain a separate lookup of value to keys. Sad.

Comment: @wim Why not as keys? Because of duplicates? They might not have any.

Comment: Yep, duplicates. Without them I guess you could (should) just use dict keys.

Comment: my dict actually does work with integer keys and object values. I got 10x acceleration by using your suggestion.